# How to design Customised progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to design customized progress-bar. Please help me in implementing this. I am using two images one is for background of progress-bar and other is one for progressing.

Comment: Whatever you have tried, post here.

Comment: what type of progress bar you want ? Please post any image if you have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we must wait for some task to complete in a modern graphical user interface the interface normally provides visual feedback that something is happening, often with an indication of how much progress has been made on the task. The widgets providing this information are commonly termed progress bars (though they need not be bars), and are essential to providing a sense of application responsiveness for the user.

Implementing a progress bar also provides an opportunity to illustrate two other important Android concepts: running processes on threads separate from the main user interface (UI) and communicating between threads. In this example we shall demonstrate how to implement progress bars and to update them from processes running on a separate thread. 
**here it is what your require : [Example](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/)**